# Accessing GMail with GMail client and JavaMail (via pop3)

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, imap, pop3

I've written a JavaMail client to access a GMail account via POP3.
As expected, I can only read a message once.  When I re-run the client, the message is not found as it has been deleted from the server.

However, when I then log onto the GMail account (IMAP enabled) via a browser, the message appears.

Why does this happen?  Are separate copies of the email created for POP3 and IMAP?

Answer (score 0):

POP3 clients access the inbox, and what they see is unseen mail. When the POP3 client has seen a message it's no longer unseen and the POP3 server is supposed to do something.

The gmail server probably moves the message to the Archived folder.

You may have won a prize as the last person to have written a POP3 client, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail has specific special handling for POP3 account:

In the default mode, it expects a 'download and delete' client.  It will only expose 300 or so messages until those are `DELE`ted.  They are not actually deleted, but they are removed from the pool of messages to be sent through POP3.  This prevents some of the inefficiencies with traditional POP3 clients accessing huge mailboxes, but does allow the client to eventually access everything.

The other mode is recent mode.  You can use this mode by putting "recent:" in front of your login, like "recent:bob@gmail.com".  This switches it to a mode where it will only show your client the most recent 30 days worth of messages.  The messages do not disappear, until they fall out of the window.  Again, this limits the size of the message list to a reasonable number for efficiency reasons, but in a different way.  However, deletes can be synced between clients.  (This may mean archiving in the Google Way).  Recent mode is currently documented [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en) in the troubleshooting section *I want to download emails on multiple email clients*.

Or, you could just use IMAP.  Even without using all the additional features of IMAP, you can do everything you can do with POP3, but will allow many other features as your client evolves.